# MySQL UTC to local time zone

Tags: mysql, timezone

I use mysql for my application and the application is business hour driven.

Now the time in my system is

> 8:53 PM. (EST)

```
select now();   -> returns 2015-10-21 20:52:48 

select utc_timestamp(); -> returns 2015-10-22 00:53:50
```

I would like to convert the time to user timezone specific time.

So use the below query to convert to user specific timezone.

```
select CONVERT_TZ(utc_timestamp(),'+00:00','-05:00');
```

The above query returns

> 2015-10-21 19:55:49

It considers daylight saving time. But, I would like this to return the current time in my system > 2015-10-21 20:55:49.

Is there anyway to instruct the convert tz query not to consider daylight saving?

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
```

The above query returns

> -04:00:00

I expect this to return -05:00 as I am in EST.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you have it backwards.  When you specify `-05:00`, that is *not* considering daylight saving time.  It can't, as you only provided an offset.

Later, you said you expected it to return `-05:00`, but if you are in US Eastern time, then currently (until Nov 1, 2015) daylight saving time is in effect.  You are in EDT, which is `-04:00`.

So `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);` is giving the correct result.  If you want `CONVERT_TZ` to give the correct result, then you would do this:

```
select CONVERT_TZ(utc_timestamp(),'+00:00','SYSTEM');
```

Passing `SYSTEM` uses the system's local time zone, which is what you asked for.  However, it's usually a better idea to use a *named* time zone, such as `America/New_York`.  To use these, ensure your MySQL installation is set up correctly for [time zone support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html).